# Google Maven repository in Artifactory - can't connect

Tags: maven, repository, artifactory

I tried to add a remote proxy repository in Artifactory.  I tried both:
  1. https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/
  2. https://maven.google.com/

I clicked on the 'Test' button and it works, but when I browsed the repository under 'Artifacts', nothing is shown.  When I tried the same for Maven Central repository, it works. Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Browsing only shows the artifacts that were already downloaded. A fresh repository has not downloaded anything. JCenter is a special case because it downloads a catalogue.

When you build against one of the google repositories, they will start to download the relevant artifacts and you will start seeing files in the browsing view.